# Method Illuminate\View\View::paginate does not exist. laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get all the results where the user's status is teacher (which is a field in my table).

When I tried to use pagination, it runs into an error.

Here is my code in the controller where I'm fetching the results:

```
public function index()
{
    $status = User::where('status', '=', 'teacher')->get();

    return view('Profile.alluser')->with('status', $status)->paginate(3);
}
```

*note laravel version is 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paginate a Query, while you are trying to paginate a view, please try the code below:

```
public function index()
{
    $status = User::where('status', '=', 'teacher')->paginate(3);

    return view('Profile.alluser')->with('status', $status);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped, please accept the answer so it can helps others as well 